# Which domains in $\mathbb R^n$ have the homology groups of a disk?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Very straightforward question, as in the title. I am wondering whether "homology disks" are a thing.

Comment: A disk is contractible so it only has $H_0 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Any contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has this property.

Comment: You mean, acyclic subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? I.e. path connected $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $H_\bullet(U) = 0$ in positive degrees?

Comment: Any finite simplicial complex embeds in some $\mathbb R^n$, so in particular all finite acyclic simplicial complexes work.

Comment: Low dimensions: for $n=1$ these are just intervals and for $n=2$ these are exactly the contractible open subsets.

Comment: @Thorgott I understand that the case $n = 1$ is simply because connected sets are intervals, hence contractible; but would you mind giving an outline of the proof for $n =2$?

Comment: Fundamental groups of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are free. By the easy Hurewicz theorem, if $\pi_1$ were not zero, $H_1$ would not be zero. So then the set is simply connected and the general Hurewicz theorem plus the Whitehead theorem implies that it is homotopy equivalent to a point, i.e. contractible.

Comment: I think the subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ obtained from the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) by adding a curve that joins the right-hand end to the origin (without meeting the rest of the curve) has the homology of a disk but is not contractible.

Comment: When you say "domains" in the title? Is that what you really meant? (Bit odd if you do because "disk" doesn't imply "open".)

Comment: @RobArthan I take "domain" to be an open, connected subset. More generally (and less trivially), a subset of the plane that has the homotopy type of  a CW complex should be acyclic iff contractible. Your example shows this needn't hold for more general spaces.

Comment: @THorgott: yes, I realised that when I saw the word "domain" in the title. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I was looking more at the suggestions in the comments that aren't restricted to open subsets.

Comment: @RobArthan Actually you are still not far off. You may take a regular neighborhood of the acyclic complex to get a domain, and if your acyclic domain is bounded and its closure is homotopy equivalent to it (pretty reasonable), then it will deformation retract onto a compact acyclic simplicial complex.

Comment: @Thorgott since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron, so is each open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, which therefore admits a CW structure. A closed subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ has CW homotopy type if and only if its inclusion is a cofibration if and only if it is a neighbourhood retract. Any CW complex which embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally closed and a neighbourhood retract. I don't know any way to determine whether a non-open, non-closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has CW homotopy type. Your comment at least characterises the contractibility of open, and certain closed, subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @connormalin I think your comment was more likely directed to guidoar rather than me.